# How to get hyperparameters of xgb.train in python

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

`xgb.train` is the low level API to train an `xgboost` model in Python.

- When I use `XGBClassifier`, which is a wrapper and calls `xgb.train` when
  a model is trained, I can print the `XGBClassifier` object and the
  hyperparameters are printed.
- When using `xgb.train` I have no idea how to check the parameters after
  training

Code:

```py
bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain)
bst.params # does not work!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `save_config` method noted [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) can be used to create a string representation of the model's configuration. This can be converted to a dict:

```
import json

config = json.loads(bst.save_config())
```

The result is somewhat deeply nested, but the hyperparameters are found like this:

```
config['learner']['gradient_booster']['updater']['grow_colmaker']['train_param']
```